# Getting image URL's from amazon product page

Tags: json, regex, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape image URL's from Amazon products, for example, [this link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00XLSS79Y).

In the page source code, there is a section which contains all the urls for images of different sizes (large, medium, hirez, etc). I can get that part of the script by doing, with scrapy,

```
imagesString = (response.xpath('//script[contains(., "ImageBlockATF")]/text()').extract_first())
```

Which gives me a string that looks like this,

```
P.when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){
    var data = {
                'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81FED1p-sTL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31HoKqtljqL._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31HoKqtljqL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81FED1p-sTL._SX355_.jpg":[308,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81FED1p-sTL._SX450_.jpg":[390,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81FED1p-sTL._SX425_.jpg":[369,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81FED1p-sTL._SX466_.jpg":[404,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81FED1p-sTL._SX522_.jpg":[453,522],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81FED1p-sTL._SX569_.jpg":[494,569],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81FED1p-sTL._SX679_.jpg":[589,679]},"variant":"MAIN","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81e8905DlhL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31Y%2B8oE5DtL._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31Y%2B8oE5DtL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81e8905DlhL._SX355_.jpg":[308,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81e8905DlhL._SX450_.jpg":[390,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81e8905DlhL._SX425_.jpg":[369,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81e8905DlhL._SX466_.jpg":[404,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81e8905DlhL._SX522_.jpg":[453,522],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81e8905DlhL._SX569_.jpg":[494,569],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81e8905DlhL._SX679_.jpg":[589,679]},"variant":"PT01","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":null,"thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51rORrvh0hL._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51rORrvh0hL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51rORrvh0hL._SX355_.jpg":[236,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51rORrvh0hL._SX450_.jpg":[300,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51rORrvh0hL._SX425_.jpg":[283,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51rORrvh0hL._SX466_.jpg":[310,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51rORrvh0hL.jpg":[333,500]},"variant":"PT02","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":null,"thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41L2OU5rPyL._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41L2OU5rPyL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41L2OU5rPyL._SX355_.jpg":[236,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41L2OU5rPyL._SX450_.jpg":[300,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41L2OU5rPyL._SX425_.jpg":[283,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41L2OU5rPyL._SX466_.jpg":[310,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41L2OU5rPyL.jpg":[333,500]},"variant":"PT03","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":null,"thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BsCYjx6OL._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BsCYjx6OL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BsCYjx6OL._SX355_.jpg":[236,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BsCYjx6OL._SX450_.jpg":[300,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BsCYjx6OL._SX425_.jpg":[283,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BsCYjx6OL._SX466_.jpg":[310,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BsCYjx6OL.jpg":[333,500]},"variant":"PT04","lowRes":null}]},
                'colorToAsin': {'initial': {}},
                'holderRatio': 1.0,
                'holderMaxHeight': 700,
                'heroImage': {'initial': []},
                'heroVideo': {'initial': []},
                'spin360ColorData': {'initial': {}},
                'spin360ColorEnabled': {'initial': 0},
                'spin360ConfigEnabled': false,
                'spin360LazyLoadEnabled': false,
                'playVideoInImmersiveView':'false',
                'tabbedImmersiveViewTreatment':'T2',
                'totalVideoCount':'0',
                'videoIngressATFSlateThumbURL':'',
                'mediaTypeCount':'0',
                'atfEnhancedHoverOverlay' : true,
                'winningAsin': 'B00XLSS79Y',
                'weblabs' : {},
                'aibExp3Layout' : 1,
                'aibRuleName' : 'frank-powered',
                'acEnabled' : false
                };
    A.trigger('P.AboveTheFold'); // trigger ATF event.
    return data;
});
```

My goal is to get into a Json dictionary the data inside `colorImages`, so then I can easily get each URL.

I tried doing something like this:

```
m = re.search(r'^var data = ({.*};)', imagesString , re.S | re.M)
data = m.group()
jsonObj = json.loads(data[:-1].replace("'", '"'))
```

But it seems that `imagesString` does not work well with `re.search`, I keep getting errors regarding `imagesString` not being a string when it actually is.

I got similar data from an amazon page by using `re.findall`, something like this (`script` is a chunk of text i got from the page).

```
variationValues = re.findall(r'variationValues\" : ({.*?})', ' '.join(script))[0]
```

and then

```
variationValuesDict = json.loads(variationValues)
```

But my knowledge of regular expressions is not that great.

From the string I pasted above, I erased the start and end so only the data remained, so I was left with this:

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=9ea92643044f4ac88bcc3e76d98425fc

I can't figure out how to get `colorImages` with `re.findall()` (or the data in the json editor) so I can then load it into Json and use it like a dictionary, any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: What typeOf() does python output for imagesString? Or does it just give String?

Comment: It's giving `NoneType`, I have tried forcing it to be a string with `str()` with no success

Comment: After trying new things that came to mind out, problem relies on `.extract_first` not really extracting any data. I'll post any new findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to initially convert the `var data` to the correct markup json. It is easy ))) Just replace all chars `'` to `"` and delete **SPACES**. And you will get json object:
[image]
(It's your right json)
[image]